# Visual Studio: как добавить текстовый файл в C#-проект и отобразить его в древе проекта?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Во всех примерах по работе с текстовыми файлами (расширение `.txt`) на языке C#, которые я видел, текстовый файл предлагалось сохранять вне проекта. Но я хочу, чтобы текстовый файл хранился внутри решения (например, в подпапке `Data`). Visual Studio в меню добавления нового файла предлагает добавлять только определённые типы файлов, среди которых нет текстовых. Таким образом, насколько я на данный момент знаю, текстовый файл можно добавить в проект только с помощью проводника Windows (или сторонних аналогов). Если это сделать, то хотя тест на наличие файла (код ниже) и даст положительный результат, файл не будет отображаться в древе проекта.

```
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Visual Studio в меню добавления нового файла предлагает добавлять
> только определённые типы файлов, среди которых нет текстовых.

Разве? В окне добавления новго элемента выберите раздел "Общие" и Вы увидите в числе прочих "Текстовый файл".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если файл создан вне студии, в конктекстном меню проекта есть пункт "Добавить"-> "Существующий элемент". Он откроет стандартный диалог Windows для открытия файлов. Выбираете в правом нижнем углу "Все файлы" и можете добавить в проект какой угодно файл. В том числе текстовый.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Прошу прощения, я действительно недостаточно внимательно искал нужный тип файлов.

Comment: Стоит добавить еще про опцию Copy to Output Directory, думаю, автору ведь нужно чтобы файл копировался в выходную директорию

Comment: Есть хороший шанс, что автору нужно включить файл как ресурс.